# Google Maps v2 Expected 4030500 found 0 exception

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I´ve looked at several posts of this poblem but I cannot fix it.

I get this error when I try to run my MapView

```
 12-03 10:26:20.865: E/AndroidRuntime(3317): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-    
data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.
  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the 
<application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I´ve added this to my manifest

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API_KEY" />
```

I´ve also tried this

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.gms.version"
    android:value="4030500"
/>
```

Manifest in google play services lib:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms"
    android:versionCode="4030530"
    android:versionName="4.0.30 (889083-30)" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
</manifest>
```

And I have no idea why it won´t work for me.

I´m using a HTC Sensation android 4.0.3 version as my emulator.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261305/google-maps-api-v2-crash-fatal-exception/20261706#20261706 Did you set the version tag in the application section? Also, please post your full logcat. Thanks.

Comment: It's the Google Play Services version number. Starting from that version, it's mandatory to specify into the manifest the version of the library you would like to use in your application.

Comment: Added more information.

Comment: look at the error then look at what you have in your manifest, it clearly does not match

Answer (score 8):

you should put meta datas in the manifest file ,after the end of activity and before closing application

```
< /activity>

        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your key from google developers console" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
< /application>
```

and dont forget to import google-play-services_lib in your workspace